Removing my tree roots from my front yard
My neighbor removed the tree that was in between the divided line of our property. Once removed the roots, manage to grow to our side of the property. She removed the tree but managed to break my sprinkler Pipeline and the roots were all around my pipeline. Is it bad that I left the roots in the bottom of the ground and not removed all of them? Will they grow back? Will I have concerns later on in the near future?I did manage to remove the big roots around my sprinklers but there was old rotten roots that were so deep I couldn't manage to get to them without going deeper into my yard but I did leave dead small ones that I couldn't manage to pull or cut off?Should I be worried

What kind of tree? Any pictures?
